# Bézout's identity or something else, how to solve?

Tags: polynomials

Arrange polynomial: $P(x)=(5x−1)(2+x)−(8−3x)^2−49x+62$. Prove that $P(x)≤0$ for $x∈R$. When $P(x)=0$?

I solved first part and arragned polynomial: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcrYx.jpg)

Now how to solve part when I need to prove $P(x)≤0$?

Comment: You might try the quadratic formula.

Comment: How to do that? I can't realize this, I spent more than 2 hours on sloving this polynomials

Answer (score 0):

You got (rightly so) that $P(X)=-3(X^2+2X+1)=-3(X+1)^2\leq 0$. On top we have $P(-1)=0$ and this is the only (double) root.